# Is there a scale function with which I can use 4 breaks points?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient

I try to do a map with a fill gradient.
I used scale_fill_gradient2 with low (0), high (150) and mid point (70).
But I'd like to have 4 breaks (= 0, 50, 100, 150).
Is that possible ?

```
plot_grid(volPM, var = "V") +
     geom_sf(
      data = carte_greco,
      col = "black",
      size = 0.3,
      fill = "transparent"
    ) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(na.value = "transparent", low = "#edf8e9", mid = "#00943c", midpoint = 70,
            high = "#004529", limits =c(0,150), name = "V")
```

[image: ggsave]

I tried with breaks = and values = ... but doesn't work.

```
plot_grid(volPM, var = "V")  +
    geom_sf(
      data = carte_greco,
      col = "black",
      size = 0.3,
      fill = "transparent"
    ) +
  scale_fill_gradient(breaks = c(0,50,100,150), values = c("#edf8e9", "#00943c", "#004529", "#004529"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't with the `gradient2` variant, but you can with the `gradientn` variant. In the example below, I'll be using a built-in dataset to illustrate. Let's say we want to have a colour gradient from red to gold to green to blue. Moreover, we want red at 0, gold at 50, green at 100 and blue at 150.

The only tricky bit here is that the `values` argument, which you can use as breaks where the (pure) colour appears, expects values between 0-1 representing the position between the lower and upper limit of the data. Hence, we should explicitly declare the limits and rescale our breaks to fit in the 0-1 range.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- reshape2::melt(volcano)

ggplot(df, aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colours = c("red", "gold", "green", "blue"),
    limits  = c(0, 150),
    values  = scales::rescale(c(0, 50, 100, 150), from = c(0, 150)) 
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I tried with `gradientn` but with breaks and not value and without `rescale`.

Comment: It helps to recall that `breaks` only determines where the labels are placed, not where the colours are in the gradient.